# Render plotly.js graph without GUI freezing (Web Worker?)

Tags: javascript, web-worker, plotly

I'm working on an dashboard where users can build their own visualizations (with plotly.js). 
Sometimes the complexity of these visualizations are resulting in a long rendering time which leads to a freezing Browser UI.

I've already created web-workers for other tasks in my dashboard. Maybe there is a way of rendering plotly.js graphs in a web-worker and return them to the main thread?

I know that there is no DOM/Canvas ability in web-workers. But maybe there is trick or you know a better way to prevent GUI freezing? Maybe outsourcing rendering to server with phantomjs (I've never used it so it is just a guess that it could work with pjs).

Comment: I filed an issue for this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem could be the OffscreenCanvas API: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas

You can access this API from a worker and maybe also use it directly with the library you mentioned.

But as browser support is really bad and (at least in Firefox, I don't know how it currently is with other browsers, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=801176) 2d canvas context is not supported (but if you use a library which uses WebGL that wouldn't be an issue).

As an alternative, you could use a pure javascript polyfill (it's a re-implementation) of canvas which works in WebWorkers:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-webworker
It's worth mentioning that this way no hardware acceleration is appliable.

In combination, a good solution could be created.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I find the new API very interesting. Too bad it's so experimental. I also like the other solution very much. It's a shame that I don't work on the project that needs the solution anymore. I think it's fair to mark your answer as the best answer. The ideas are comprehensible and promising!

Comment: Yes, but maybe the answer can be useful for someone else in the future! Good support for the OffscreenCanvas API would a win for the whole web. it offers so many possibilities. Let's see what the future brings.

Comment: Anything like this available for IE11?